# Decryption using AES algorithm

Tags: java, android, encryption

```
public void handleResult(Result result) {    

    final String scanResult = result.getText();    
    Log.e("QRCode:", scanResult);   

    String normalTextDec = null;
    try {
        normalTextDec = AESHelper.decrypt(seedValue, scanResult);
        Log.e("Decrypt:",normalTextDec);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the above code "scanResult" is the encrypted String. I wanted to decrypt it. When I am printing scanResult on the console it is giving the correct encrypted String but decryption is not working. Can anyone solve this? And I am using AESHelper class for this.

AESHelper class:

```
public class AESHelper {

    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String toHex(String txt) {
        return toHex(txt.getBytes());
    }

    public static String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length()/2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
            return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) 
    {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide the encryption code and expected inputs and outputs.  Read the [help].

Comment: what error or message you receive when you try to decrypt?

Comment: It doesn't produce any error. In my opinion the try block is not getting executed. @GaneshKarewad

Comment: Sir actually encryption is getting done in one project and decryption is getting done in different project. I am retrieving the encrypted string from the database into a String i.e.,"scanResult" as described in the code. @LukeJoshuaPark

Comment: Are you encrypt and decrypt on the same platform? Fyi, `SHA1PRNG` may not return same value on different platform.  For example,
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728538/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-android-and-java-different-values

Comment: Yes, I am using the same platform i.e., Android. @JoeyChong